# Swift compiler inconsistency with operator +=

Tags: swift

Compiler seems inconsistent with its compilation for +=.  Any idea why the last line has issue?

```
var num = 2;
num += 2 //Works
num+=2 // Works
num +=2 //Error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ;
```

Comment: Guys, look at the question again.  It's not the same as your link.  += should already provide enough clue to compiler that this is an operator compared to =[.